# RestEasy - How to generate a WAR compatible with Jboss 4 and Jboss 7?

Tags: jboss7.x, resteasy, jboss-4.2.x

I'm stuck on a problem for a long time. My application was designed to run with Jboss 4, but now I need it running on Jboss 7.

The problem is that when RestEasy lib (.jar) is present inside the WAR it does not work on Jboss 7, so I remove the lib and It stop working on Jboss 4.

Is there a solution that resolves the problem for working with both versions of Jboss?

Thank you very much.

Regards,

Ramon de Paula Marques

Answer (score 0):

By default JBOSS Modular class loading will load the classes from JBOSS_HOME\modules (loaded automatically by the container when it finds any class reference or annotations involving these classes), in your case it should be loading JBOSS_HOME\modules\org\jboss\resteasy, since you have your lib files inside the war file you need your application to start using your lib jar files instead of the default classes from the jar provided by JBOSS that might conflict with your application. You can achieve this either

1. By replacing the jars with your version in the path JBOSS_HOME\modules\org\jboss\resteasy (make sure the name of the jar files are consistent)
2. or by declaring your dependencies in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

More more insight [this post](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) might be helpful in determining what suits best for your class loading needs
Hope its helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but both options didn't work for me, the second one almost resolve, but generated the error "Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap", the solution for that is remove the jars, but if i do that I will need to generate another version with the jars to run on jboss 4 and I don't want to generate two versions.

Comment: In "declaring your dependencies" did you use `<dependencies>` or `<exclusions>`? To exclude the JBoss libs, you need to use `<exclusions>`.